# Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, entity

I am new in spring boot. When I tried to learn entity mapping (simple CRUD project), I got some problems in ManyToMany mapping and cannot solve that. I followed many solution and tried but can not solve this problem.
There are 2 entity. One is Student and One is Subject.

**Student Entity:**

```
package com.example.demoschoolrelational.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data //lombok
@Entity
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long roll;
    private String studentName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "enrolledStudent",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

//    @JsonIgnoreProperties("enrolledStudent")
//    @JsonIgnore

    @JsonManagedReference(value = "enrolledStudent")
    private Set<Subject> enrolledSubject = new HashSet<>();

    public void enrollSubject(Subject sub1) {
        enrolledSubject.add(sub1);
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student thatStudent) {
        long rollCompare = ((Student) thatStudent).getRoll();
        return (int)(this.roll-rollCompare);
    }
}
```

**Subject Entity:**

```
package com.example.demoschoolrelational.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String subjectName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(  
            name = "student_enrolled_sub",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    )
    @JsonBackReference(value = "enrolledSubject")
//    @JsonIgnoreProperties("enrolledSubject")
    private Set<Student> enrolledStudent = new HashSet<>();  

}
```

**Error Msg:**

```
2022-10-06 15:48:23.839  WARN 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.demoschoolrelational.entity.Student["enrolledSubject"])]
2022-10-06 15:48:23.841  WARN 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@10e0ce3e<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@2034992128 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@29eb4bd>
2022-10-06 15:48:23.841  WARN 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@62b79155<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@821266690 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@3a4ffafb>
2022-10-06 15:48:23.841  WARN 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@2c4852b2<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1276455940 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@5b0420da>
2022-10-06 15:48:23.841  WARN 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@5673fd6<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1015611142 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@40ba95a3>
2022-10-06 15:48:23.841  WARN 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@2e8992c4<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@263607175 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@5471653f>
2022-10-06 15:48:23.841  WARN 21576 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@685469e8<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1949976072 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@7c57fecc>
```

I tried @JsonIgnoreProperties("enrolledStudent"),  @JsonIgnore ,  @JsonManagedReference(value = "enrolledStudent"). I got all subject list.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subjectName": "subject1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "subjectName": "subject2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "subjectName": "subject3"
    }
]
```

But can not get the student list. Got error and that is:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-06T09:48:23.868+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/students"
}
```

How can I solve this error? Thank You.

Comment: You better use a DTO on your WebService